# Text file search for match strings regex

Tags: powershell, text, scripting

I am trying to understand how regex works and what are the possibilities of working with it.
So I have a txt file and I am trying to search for 8 char long strings containing numbers. for now I use a quite simple option:

```
clear
Get-ChildItem random.txt | Select-String -Pattern [0-9][a-z] | foreach {$_.line}
```

It sort of works but I am trying to find a better option. ATM it takes too long to read through the left out text since it writes entire lines and it does not filter them by length.

Comment: It would help for us to see an example of the input you have, and an example of what you would like it to look like - anonymized/cleaned of any real-world data, of course.

Comment: @gravity hay well the input is smth like code 
<li>2a324b2f</li>
</ul>
</div>

what i am trying to get is the 2a324b2f, in a text file or in powershell

Comment: If you have HTML input you [shouldn't use regular expressions in the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers well great thanks that explains a lot

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers well i have truly enjoyed this comparison "While it is true that asking regexes to parse arbitrary HTML is like asking Paris Hilton to write an operating system"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that a string contains at least 1 digit, then specify the length of the match and finally anchor it with `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) if the string is on a line of its own, or `\b` (word boundary) if it's part of an `HTML` document as your comments seem to suggest:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\files\ |Select-String -Pattern '^(?=.*\d)\w{8}$'
Get-ChildItem C:\files\ |Select-String -Pattern '\b(?=.*\d)\w{8}\b'
```

Comment: i would have suggested http://regexone.com/ for a tutorial instead. can do it within the browser with inline validation.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer i made a bit of an update in the comments :) will try thanks

Comment: thanks for the update :) should be output be done like i did previously in this case?

Comment: If you want the match, rather than the full string, you should look at `$_.Matches` instead of `$_.Line`

Comment: @Hazonko You're more than welcome to update my post with a link to a better learning resource for lookaheads if you feel so inclined :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen well thanks that helps a lot i just write it like this get-childitem  |  select-string -pattern [0-9][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][<]| foreach {$_.Matches}

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `[0-9][a-z]` matches a digit followed by a letter. If you want to match a sequence of 8 characters use `.{8}`. The dot in regular expressions matches any character except newlines. A number in curly brackets matches the preceding expression the given number of times.

If you want to match non-whitespace characters use `\S` instead of `.`. If you want to match only digits and letters use `[0-9a-z]` (a character class) instead of `.`.

For a more thorough introduction please go find a tutorial. The subject is *way* too complex to be covered by a single answer on SO.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer i made a bit of an update in the comments :) will try thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently searching for is a single number ranging from 0-9 followed by a single lowercase letter ranging from a-z.

this, for example, will match any 8 char long strings containing only alphanumeric characters.

```
\w{8}
```

i often forget what some regex classes are, and it may be useful to you as a learning tool, but i use this as a point of reference: http://regexr.com/

It can also validate what you're typing inline via a text field so you can see if what you're doing works or not.

If you need more of a tutorial than a reference, i found this extremely useful when i learned: [regexone.com](http://regexone.com)

Comment: @tuarianking using your example in your comment above, it does match to what you're trying to get.